# To get meta field (ACF) in taxonomy template

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I am in a taxonomy page, in a custom taxonomy and specific term URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/personas/cristina-aiken-soux/
```

Also, I have a taxonomy template for this page:

```
taxonomy-personas.php
```

Inside this template, I am trying to recover and show an Advanced Custom Field:

```
$term_object = get_queried_object();
the_field('picture', $term_object->term_id);
```

But nothig is returned. Why?

If i do `print_r($term_object);` I can see the queried object:

```
WP_Term Object ( 
    [term_id] => 2 [name] => Cristina Aiken Soux 
    [slug] => cristina-aiken-soux 
    [term_group] => 0 
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 2 
    [taxonomy] => personas 
    [description] => Cras in elementum enim, vitae volutpat sapien. Duis at sem in quam ultrices hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent. 
    [parent] => 0 
    [count] => 2 
    [filter] => raw 
)
```

So, why can not I recover de ACF?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see "picture" in your $term_object?

Comment: Have you tried get_field function of ACF??

Comment: May be this will help: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

Comment: Yes, I tried both, get_field an the_field. Thanks!

Comment: Picture is not in the term_objet, for this reason I use $term_object->term_id to get cusom field: the_field('picture', $term_object->term_id);

Comment: Yes, I had already read this ACF documentation page.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!

Comment: can you show us waht happens if you var_dump(get_fields($term_object->term_id));

Comment: Yes! I got this: /srv/www/soux-calvo.dev/current/web/app/themes/sc/taxonomy-personas.php:10:boolean false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution

```
$foto = get_field('fotopersona', 'personas'.'_'.$term_object->term_id);
```